# Looking for an efficient way to detect birthday ranges using Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, sinatra

Currently working on an app that needs to show the operator a list of staff that have birthdays that fall in the past 7 days or the next 21 days.

We have a staff database that contains the date of births, and selecting them by date range is fairly straightforward.  However, we then have to show how many days in the future/past the birthday is from today.

The code currently looks something like:

```
today = Date.today
dob = staff.dob

days = Date.new(today.year, dob.month, dob.day) - today

if days < 0
    "#{ days.abs } days ago"
else
    "in #{ days } days"
end
```

This all works well in nearly every case, *except* when it comes to late December, or very early January.  Because we are using `today.year` as the year comparator, if the 21 days ahead spills over into the new year, I get a false "days ago" reading. e.g.

Today's date is `20th December 2015`, and the staff member's birthday is on `2nd January`, instead of getting `"in 13 days"`, I am getting `"352 days ago"`.

I know I can probably wrap the code in another if/then/else clause that checks if the current date is after December 10th, to cater for this edge case, but there is a possibility that the date ranges will change dynamically, and also, the code is starting to look messy and inelegant - not like how I would like ruby code to look.

Does anyone have a better suggestion as to how to handle this issue?

(Note: This is in a Sinatra based project, so I don't have all the ActiveSupport or Rails based magic, although I am not averse to using a gem if it will get me the results I need.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the smallest days for this year, next year and last year

```
today = Date.today
dob = staff.dob

this_dob = Date.new(today.year, dob.month, dob.day)
next_dob = this_dob.next_year
prev_dob = this_dob.prev_year
days = [this_dob - today, next_dob - today, prev_dob - today].min_by{|i| i.to_i.abs}

if days < 0
  "#{ days.abs } days ago"
else
  "in #{ days } days"
end
```

Comment: Rather than toss code out, explain why it works and is the best choice. Tossing out code is equivalent to handing the OP a fish. Explaining it is akin to teaching them how to fish. The second is much better.

Comment: Great! I did not know about the `.min_by` construct.  This definitely falls into the 'more elegant' way of achieving the end result.  And it looks easy enough to adapt to cater for the opposite edge case (i.e. if we were in early January and the birthday was in late December.  Setting a third variable of `previous.dob = this_dob.last_year` and still looking for the minimum would still give me the closes of the three birthdate options.

Comment: Suppose today is New Year's Day. You need to consider three birthdays: last year's, this year's and next year's.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I did fix it.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'

class BirthDates
  attr_reader :year, :month, :day
  def initialize(year, month, day)
    @year  = year
    @month = month
    @day   = day
  end
end

def count_days(dob)
  today = Date.today
  this_year = today.year
  days = [this_year-1, this_year, this_year+1].map { |year|
    (Date.new(year, dob.month, dob.day) - today) }.min_by(&:abs)
  if days < 0
    "#{ -days } days ago"
  elsif days > 0
    "in #{ days } days"
  else
   "Happy Birthday!"
  end
end
```

Let's try it. (Today is 29 Oct 15)

```
dob = BirthDates.new(1908, 12, 28)
count_days(dob) #=> "in 60 days"

dob = BirthDates.new(1999, 10, 27)
count_days(dob) #=> "2 days ago"

dob = BirthDates.new(2014, 10, 29)
count_days(dob) #=> "Happy Birthday"
```

If today were 5 Jan 16:

```
dob = BirthDates.new(1908, 12, 28)
count_days(dob) #=> "8 days ago"

dob = BirthDates.new(1999, 3, 27)
count_days(dob) #=> "in 82 days"
```

Comment: Thank you - definitely a great way to neatly package up the solution.  Once again, I wish I had known about `.min_by`, so I could have tried to nut it out, but I am grateful for learning something new today! :)  Cool of you to pick up the situation where the birthday = today as well.  I did have that code in a `case..when` section, but once again, learned about the `elseif` construct from your code.